# Intellij Maven Projects - missing plugins

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea, maven-plugin

My maven project plugs are in red and they wont download.  how can this be resolved?  here is an image of the maven projects fro intellij:

[image]

and here is my pom.xml file contents:

```
    <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>com.example.ema</groupId>
  <artifactId>jerseyexample</artifactId>
  <packaging>war</packaging>
  <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <name>jerseyexample Maven Webapp</name>
  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>3.8.1</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.containers</groupId>
      <artifactId>jersey-container-servlet</artifactId>
      <version>2.10.1</version>
    </dependency>


  </dependencies>



  <build>
    <finalName>jerseyexample</finalName>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.maven</groupId>
        <artifactId>tomcat7-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.2</version>
        <configuration>
          <server>TomcatServer</server>
          <path>/newjersey</path>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>


  </build>
</project>
```

i put the mouse over the first maven directory in the image called 'jerseyexample Maven Webapp' and it showed the following error, hope this helps:

[image]

and here is how i added the jersey dependencies... i simply downloaded the jar files and added them to the app module:

[image]

Comment: I take it you've noticed you aren't doing a `</project>`

Comment: Also have you tried to force a  reimport these plugins?

Comment: First, you should try to download theses plugins with Maven in command line to verify if it is an IDEA problem or a Maven/system problem.

Comment: do you now the command to install a plugin from the command line ..the one i really need is the tomcat7 maven plugin.

Comment: hi Adam, yes i've tried to force a re-import. it does not do anything.  i updated the question with a screenshot of the error.

Comment: Try a `mvn clean install` both from within IntelliJ and externally from command line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the issue was with my settings.xml file that maven uses to build the project. I had a mirror defined in there that used a proxy and it was blocking the download